# Reshape pandas columns into numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, reshape

I have a very long dataframe with many columns of the form `k1, p1, k2, p2,...,kn, pn` such as

```
       k1         p1           k2             p2           k3         p3 ...    
-0.001870   0.000659    -0.005000       0.000795    -0.003889   0.000795 ...
-0.002778   0.000556     0.000795       0.001667     0.000795   0.002778 ...
```

How could I build, in the most pythonic way, a numpy array with the k's and p's separated into arrays, like `[[[-0.001870,-0.005000,-0.003889,...],[0.000659,0.000795,0.000795...]],[[-0.002778, 0.000795, 0.000795...],[0.000556, 0.001667, 0.002778...]], ...[[...],[...]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
out = df.to_numpy().reshape((len(df), 2, -1), order='F')
```

Output:

```
array([[[-0.00187 , -0.005   , -0.003889],
        [ 0.000659,  0.000795,  0.000795]],

       [[-0.002778,  0.000795,  0.000795],
        [ 0.000556,  0.001667,  0.002778]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your case the columns are alternating between `k` and `p` but just in case it's not always the case, you can do:

```
k_matrix = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("k")]].to_numpy()
p_matrix = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("p")]].to_numpy()
```